# Bigcommerce PHP API, get the email addresses of all newsletter subscriber, not using control panel

Tags: bigcommerce

As state in the title, I want to get the email addresses from all my newsletter subscriber. Since this is just part of what I need to code up, dumping out the info into a csv file using Bigcommerce control panel is not an option.

So far, what I had figured out is getting the addresses from ALL the customers. Is there a filter I can apply so to filter the non-subscriber out of this list? Or there are other ways to approach this problem?

Thank you in advance for any helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, it is not possible thru the Bigcommerce API. There are no fields for the customers resource to indicate if they signed up for the newsletter or not.
Furthermore, there is no API access to any of the newsletter content at all. 
Please reference https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/customers

If you were not aware, Bigcommerce already integrates directly (and nicely) with MailChimp. If you are set on using your own email marketing programs, simply have Bigcommerce integrate with MailChimp to port the newsletter subscribers over, and then you can look into connecting to the MailChimp API to grab the necessary data: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com